# Countries names list or file translated to common languages

Tags: localization

Does anyone can tell me where can I find countries names translated to most common languages like: French, Deutch, Portoguese, Spanish etc.

Is there a file or a database containing this information ?

I need it for a multilingual site containing a drop-down list of countries.

Comment: https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list

Comment: I also add this one : https://github.com/onomojo/i18n-country-translations

Answer (score 3):

There's a big list at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_names_in_various_languages_%28A-C%29

it's not in Excel format... but a little scripting would be able to pull out what you need.

This is a good reference for: http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/countrynames_german.htm

- English
- German
- Chinese
- French
- Arabic
- Italian
- Russian
- Spanish

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I could find. It's not a a single file or a database but these sites have the information.

3rd Column

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_capitals_in_native_languages

This ones a little harder to navigate

http://www.omniglot.com/countries/

Comment: thank you very much. it helped me indeed, although i need more like a CVS file or EXCEL file.